# reCAPTCHA: Do not access .getDOMNode()

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha, dom-node

I've been trying to implement reCAPTCHA into my react app but when everything finally seemed ok I checked console and found this warning:

`Warning: ReactDOMComponent: Do not access .getDOMNode() of a DOM node; instead, use the node directly. This DOM node was rendered by 'reCAPTCHA'.`

My current versions of packages:

```
`"react": "^0.14.7",
"react-dom": "^0.14.7",
"react-google-recaptcha": "^0.4.1",`
```

Tried to fix this by downgrading to `react@0.14.0` but it didn't help.

EDIT:

Code:

```
onChange(response) {
  console.log("Captcha value:", value);
  this.setState({
    'g-recaptcha-response': response
  });
}
render() {
 return (
    <ReCAPTCHA
      ref="recaptcha"
      sitekey="6Le0bCoUAAAAAMnfIWvY2b8w0Z932kI6Iu_zu3p9"
      onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
    />
 );
}
```

And server side:

```
const recaptcha = require('express-recaptcha');
recaptcha.init(process.env.CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY, 
process.env.CAPTCHA_SECRET);

module.exports = {
    captchaVerify(req, res, next) {
    recaptcha.verify(req, (err) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.status(200).send({ err: 'Approved' });
      } else {
        res.status(422).send({ err: 'Disapproved' })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @DannyDelott here it is! /\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of `react-google-recaptcha`, which leads to [an error/warning with React 14](https://github.com/dozoisch/react-google-recaptcha/issues/11). Try upgrading with:

```
npm install --save react-google-recaptcha@0.9.6
```

If that doesn't work, change the version to [`0.5.1`](https://github.com/dozoisch/react-google-recaptcha/releases/tag/v0.5.1), it's the release that introduced support for React 14.

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem!

But now I've got another one: 

`Uncaught Error: ReCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty`. I found that it indicates that this library is loaded twise but I only use `import ReCAPTCHA from 'react-google-recaptcha';` statement.

Comment: Which version of `react-google-recaptcha` are you using now?

Comment: Updating it from `0.5.0` to `0.5.1` fixed the issue. Thank you, Fabian!